# Spring boot application doesnt start on JDK update to 8

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a vm running ubuntu server 14.04, I updated the open-jdk-7 to oracle-jdk-8. prior to that, the catalina log file said that it needed the updated version of java in order to run our spring-boot-application. hence the update.
now, the application wont start even.

I am newbie to java, so i dont know whats wrong. what i think that spring-boot things are missing.

Here is the exception i am getting.

```
[localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive /opt/tomcat/webapps/ROOT.war
18-Mar-2017 05:33:54.925 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.getDefaultWebXmlFragment No global web.xml found
18-Mar-2017 05:33:57.454 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
18-Mar-2017 05:34:02.126 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:940)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1816)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConverters org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.messageConverters; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private final java.util.List org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.converters; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]: Error creating bean with name 'objectMapper' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]: Factory method 'objectMapper' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'config' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration]: Factory method 'config' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceMappings' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.mapping.ResourceMappings]: Factory method 'resourceMappings' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositories' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories]: Factory method 'repositories' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gbxServiceInstallerRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#595423f' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#595423f': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'objectMapper' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]: Factory method 'objectMapper' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'config' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration]: Factory method 'config' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceMappings' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.mapping.ResourceMappings]: Factory method 'resourceMappings' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositories' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories]: Factory method 'repositories' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gbxServiceInstallerRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#595423f' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#595423f': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:133)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:149)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:129)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5240)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConverters org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.messageConverters; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private final java.util.List org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration.converters; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration$MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverterConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]: Error creating bean with name 'objectMapper' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper]: Factory method 'objectMapper' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'config' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.config.RepositoryRestConfiguration]: Factory method 'config' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'resourceMappings' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.rest.core.mapping.ResourceMappings]: Factory method 'resourceMappings' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repositories' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/rest/SpringBootRepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.repository.support.Repositories]: Factory method 'repositories' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'gbxServiceInstallerRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#595423f' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#595423f': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]:
```

Comment: The underlying problem is with Hibernate. Can you shared your Hibernate and database-related configuration?

Comment: Try to remove 'hibernate.dialect' option or check your hibernate related options.

Comment: I am totally new to JAVA and especially to Spring, @AndyWilkinson, can you please tell me where i can find hibernate configuration?

Comment: @FıratKÜÇÜK: can you please elaborate a bit, how to accomplish it that you are suggesting. thankful for your precious time.

Comment: In a typical Spring Boot application your Hibernate configuration would be in application.properties or application.yml

Comment: As @AndyWilkinson said please update your question with your database configuration file.

Comment: Thanx guys, looks like, updating the JDK solved the problem